# Copying a PIL image as quickly as I can open it

Tags: python, performance, time, python-imaging-library

I'm finding that in PIL I can load an image from disk substantially more quickly than I can copy it. Is there a faster way to copy an image than by calling image.copy()? (and how is this even possible?)

Sample code:

```
import os, PIL.Image, timeit

test_filepath = os.path.expanduser("~/Test images/C.jpg")
load_image_cmd = "PIL.Image.open('{}')".format(test_filepath)

print((PIL.Image.open(test_filepath)).__class__)
print(min(timeit.repeat(load_image_cmd, setup='import PIL.Image', number=10000)))
print(min(timeit.repeat("img.copy()", setup='import PIL.Image; img = {}'.format(load_image_cmd), number=10000)))
```

Produces:

```
PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile
0.916192054749
1.85366988182
```

Adding `gc.enable` to the setup for `timeit` doesn't change things much.

Comment: Your last `timeit` is measuring how fast an empty dictionary can be copied, not an `PIL.image`. Regardless, it's best to avoid [prematurely optimizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimization#When_to_optimize) things.

Comment: @martineau: Read again; there's a `.format(…)` after that string.

Comment: @duskwuff: Oops, you're right, missed that. Anyway, the part about optimizing things is still valid.

Comment: @martineau, re the premature optimizing question, this is stub code that I extracted out of something larger. I do this repeatedly or otherwise I would not have noticed. Does that address your concern?

Comment: Even if it's done repeatedly, doesn't mean it matters much. If opening is faster, just do that multiple times instead of copying it.

Comment: @martineau, the copy operation is being done in a different spot from where I'm opening it. I'd need to keep track of the filename to achieve that.

Comment: It would be trivial to add a `filename` attribute to the image instance returned from `PIL.Image.open()`.

Comment: @martineau, thanks for the suggestion to add a `filename` attribute! A neat thing you can do in Python and not in some other languages (which is perhaps why I didn't think of it).

Comment: You can also check to see if an image has had a `filename` attribute added by using `hasattr()` (or indirectly by trying to retrieve its value using `getattr()`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the PIL documentation, `open()` is a lazy operation, which means that it's not really doing all the work to use the image yet.

To do a `copy()` however, it almost certainly has to read the whole thing in and process it.

EDIT:

To test whether this is true, you should access a pixel in each image as part of your timeit.

EDIT 2:

Another glance at the doc shows that a `load()` after the `open()` ought to do the trick of making it do all its work.

Comment: Yes, that does it, thanks! I'm not sure how this could explain the performance anomaly I'm seeing from my program; I'll have to start from square one.

Comment: @kuzzooroo The first copy of any image was effectively doing the load() -- that would have the effect both of making the open() seem to take less time _and_ making the copy() seem to take _more_ time.